# Azure SQL Database "A task was canceled." using Active Directory Default authentication in connection string

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, .net-6.0

I have an .NET 6 Azure Function app with EF Core 6 and I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL database with Active Directory Default authentication via the connection string. However, I get a 'task canceled' exception when it attempts to fetch the access token. This occurs when debugging the function app from Visual Studio.

I'm using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0. The connection string is built like so:

`Server=tcp:{instance}.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Default;Database={db};`

When I attempt to fetch a token the "old" way using Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential and attach it to the DbConnection manually, that works fine; it's only when trying to include "Authentication=Active Directory Default" in the connection string do I run into this issue.

See the stack trace below

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A task was canceled.
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext context, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at _.Functions.Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) in C:\_\Functions.cs:line 32

Inner Exception 1:
TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.<RunProcessesAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
   at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCredential.<GetTokenAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.<GetTokenFromSourcesAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.<GetTokenAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass146_1.<<GetFedAuthToken>b__1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
```

Comment: Which Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version?

Comment: Also could you share your connectionstring => how it is built please ?

Comment: @Thomas Question updated

Comment: @ErikEJ version 4.1.0

Answer (score 2):

two options:

1. upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.5
2. increase ConnectionTimeout=30

Discussion: [Version 17.7.0 Preview 2.0 - WebApp unable to connect to SQL Managed Instance using Active Directory Default Authentication and VisualStudioCredential](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Version-1770-Preview-20---WebApp-unab/10409641?q=%22a%20task%20was%20cancelled%22&sort=newest)

Answer (score 1):

•   You are getting this error ‘A task was cancelled’ because in **‘Default Active Directory’** authentication mechanism, the SQL driver acquires a token by passing the **‘DefaultAzureCredential’** from the Azure Identity Library using various mode attempts, viz., **`EnvironmentCredential, ManagedIdentityCredential, SharedTokenCacheCredential, VisualStudioCredential, VisualStudioCodeCredential and AzureCliCredential`**, in the order as stated sequentially above.

Thus, I would suggest you check the details are configured correctly in the below **environment variables**, viz., ***`‘AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PATH, AZURE_USERNAME, AZURE_PASSWORD’`*** respectively as you would want to create an Azure app registration and **give the required permissions and scope along with the required roles also such that the Azure function app is able to retrieve a token through the connection string from Azure AD on behalf of this app/database user**.

•   Since, you are trying to connect to the SQL database through the Azure function when you are debugging it from the Visual Studio, **ensure that you are logged in to the Visual Studio console itself with the credentials of the ‘Application Owner’ of the app registered in Azure AD for database authentication with Azure AD identity**. Also, do `ensure that the app registered in the Azure AD has the required application permissions over SQL database resource in the resource group as well as the correct roles and scopes are assigned to the service principal of that application registration`. Ensure that atleast **‘Connect.dbo’ permissions are granted under the assigned role**.

•   And finally, please do **`check the inbound and outbound ports on the Azure SQL database NSG for any port blockage and try to telnet the SQL DB over those ports`** for more information.

Kindly refer to the below link for more details in this regard: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication**

Comment: Is there difference between using "Active Directory Default" authentication and using Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential to fetch/attach a token manually in the DbContext constructor? I thought the only difference was that using "Active Directory Default" just reduces this boilerplate code and that it's doing the same sort of token fetching under the hood. I want to reiterate that using Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential works just fine.

Comment: When you call the 'Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential' class, it invokes the 'Microsoft.AzureIdentity' library and accordingly calls through the app's scope to retrieve a token in the background but when you use it in the connection string, it doesn't know in what context you should use it, that's why when you are using the 'DefaultAzureCredential' from the Azure Identity library, it searches for various contexts in the order stated as above. Thus, you should provide it accordingly in the code or in the environment.

Comment: Hi @spongesuck, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Comment: Is there an environment variable I can set to have the library use my account locally and the managed identity of the function in azure? I don't want to have to create an app registration for this function app just so I can save a line of code when connecting to the db.

Comment: I don't think so because setting environment variables locally will allow you to login to Azure without the need to enter credentials while to connect to Azure, you will have to use authentication mechanism as specified and allowed by it since the token expiration factor comes into play for that purpose.